# Calling a separate json session service for session management in Yii Framework 1.0

Tags: php, yii

We have a micro-service based architecture in which all sessions needs are handled by a separate rest service using content JSON.

I have created a `SessionService` class extending `CHttpSession` with the following overridden methods:-

1. `open()`
2. `getUseCustomStorage`
3. `regenerateID`
4. `readSession`
5. `writeSession`
6. `destroySession`

This is working in most of the cases. But in some cases I am seeing some serialized date coming in `writeSession` like below:-

```
YII_CSRF_TOKEN|s:40:"a408a11e7d684ebf6d70208b";46db49e22ae1e33d11cdd0100a646632__returnUrl|s:17:"/customer/account";
```

It seems Yii is doing some serialization while writing to session.

The `writeSession` is getting called from

```
SessionService->writeSession
  session_write_close
    CHttpSession->close()
```

Since the session service only understands JSON so this call is failing. Can some one suggest me how can I use a JSON in place of the above serialization?

I am on Yii 1.0 and Php 5.3. This is very legacy code base. So don't suggest me to upgrade Yii or Php.

Comment: What else do you need? Take one of classes given as example like `CacheSession` and write your own based on this...

Comment: Updated the question.